# issue with google maps and get child fragment manager

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, supportmapfragment, child-fragment

I keep getting an error on the line for the support map fragment, i am new to android and java so, do not have the answers it's saying ';' is expected, but once inserted before the get child fragment manager, it makes the support map fragment unreachable and I get an error across the whole line.

here is my class

```
package com.example.hp_user.shoutfinal28;


import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class FragmentShouts_Maps extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragment shouts.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentshouts_maps, container, false);
    return view;

    SupportMapFragment fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(); getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);




}

@Override
public void onMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap) {

}



}
```

here is my xml file

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment android:id="@+id/maps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.example.hp_user.shoutfinal28.FragmentShouts_Maps"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
</fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this code:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentshouts_maps, container, false);
return view;
SupportMapFragment fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(); getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
fragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

with this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentshouts_maps, container, false);
SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
if (fragment!= null) {
    fragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
return view;
```

You don't need to create a new fragment. You only need a reference to your map you have already placed in your xml. Secondly `return` line is always the the last line of the function. Because once the return line is executed, remaining lines of the method is always skipped.

Comment: first line says unreachable statement @Rehan

Comment: @AlexanderRufus because you have placed the return line at wrongly. I've updated the answer. Refresh the pagge to see the updated answer

Comment: You're a genius idk why but I completely forgot that and that's been the problem all this while lol @Rehan thank you very much